# Postgres Container not see user

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker, psql

I have a problem, I'm trying to run a Postgres instance inside a docker container for it to be used in a java application. I try running the following command:

```
 docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=root -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -v postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data -P -d postgres
```

The container seems to be created successfully. But if I try to access to it to create a DB or table I do:

```
 docker exec -it postgres /bin/bash
```

If I run the following:

```
 psql -u postgres -p
```

The following response is returned:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/psql: invalid option -- 'u'
```

And that's no good for my application. I have read on the d.hub to use -e P_USER and P_Password to set it, but it doesn't work .

Comment: Try `psql postgres -p` or `psql -U postgres`

Comment: @JimJones it work without -p , but i had not set the user root pass by me

Comment: i would try to avoid naming the postgres user as root, i think this one already exist there

Comment: I ran the following:
```docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=someUser -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -p 5432:5432 -d postgres```
And then ran the following to connect:
`psql -U someUser -p 5432 -h localhost
<entered in password>
someUser=# \d
Did not find any relations`